# Global CSS cannot be imported

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, node-modules

When I start the yarn dev command, this error appears:

`error - ./src/pages/home.modules.scss`

Global CSS cannot be imported from files other than your Custom . Please move all global CSS imports to src\pages_app.tsx. Or convert the import to Component-Level CSS (CSS Modules).

Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global
Location: `src\pages\index.tsx`

But in the other pages inside the other folders i created, the error does not appear, I can easily import a scss file,this error just happen on this specific folder that I've created called pages, and yes this file named `index.tsx` are in too.

```js
import { GetStaticProps } from "next";
import Image from "next/image";
import { format, parseISO } from "date-fns";
import ptBR from "date-fns/locale/pt-BR";
import { api } from "../services/api";
import { convertDurationToTimeString } from "../utils/convertDurationToTimeString";

import styles from './home.modules.scss';
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming your `scss` file to `home.module.scss`? Next.js expects component-level CSS files to end in `.module.scss`.

Comment: Well thanks for the help but I figured out how to solve this, I had to delete "yarn.lock" and "node.modules" and install again with yarn command, also I moved the "home.module.scss" to another folder and this worked ^^. It seems that was some kind of next's bug unfortunately.